# Unknown hostname exception when trying to connect to qpid host

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

I am using qpid broker(0.28) and qpid JMS client to communicate to the broker. I want to use amqp1.0 protocol and when I try the [example given here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/branches/0.28/qpid/java/amqp-1-0-client-jms/example/), using a connection url as `amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672?clientid=test`, I get error as it is not able to connect to the qpid host

```
Caught exception: Unknown hostname localhostjavax.jms.JMSException: Unknown hostname localhost
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.(SessionImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.ConnectionImpl.createSession(ConnectionImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.ConnectionImpl.createSession(ConnectionImpl.java:210)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.ConnectionImpl.createSession(ConnectionImpl.java:40)
```

When I change my connection url to `amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672?clientid=test&remote-host=default` I get an error as

```
Caused by: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender$SenderCreationException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: ping
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:185)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:113)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:106)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:92)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:78)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.(Sender.java:72)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Session$1.(Session.java:90)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Session.createSender(Session.java:89)
```

Can someone please help in understanding what exactly is happening? What wrong am I doing?

Comment: This is a name resolution problem, not a Java problem... But not being able to resolve `localhost`? Your system must be seriously screwed up

Comment: Instead of lcalhost try 127.0.0.1. Perhaps localhost is not defined in /etc/hosts. Assuming it is a Unix.

Comment: I tried giving 127.0.0.1 and also my up address still getting the same error. For non amqp 1.0 it works fine but facing issues with amqp1.0